# How to delete files from another server using a shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

Suppose we have two servers 'A' and 'B'.

Server B:

> Directory structure: `/a/b/c/`
>
> The above directory has the files below:
>
> ```
> 2016xzy
> 2016abc
> 2016pqr
> 2015ghj
> ```

1. I want to delete all files which have names starting with `2016` from server B (`/a/b/c/`).
2. The shell script should be on server 'A'.
3. The pattern (i.e. `2016`) should be taken as a variable in the shell script.

Comment: "from one server to another" - should be "from" another? Using "to" sounds like you want to _move_ the files. (?)

Answer (score 9):

Just do, from `server_A`:

```
ssh server_B 'rm -- /a/b/c/2016*'
```

Passing starting pattern as variable:

```
var=2016
ssh server_B "rm -- /a/b/c/${var}*"
```